# How to display the added element in an array in my html document?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do here is to display only the added element in the array on the HTML page?
But whenever I add an element using the unshift array method it displays other elements of the array too.

```js
let greetings = ["I", "Hi", "Hello"];
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = greetings;

greetings.unshift("Hey");
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = greetings;
```

```html
<h3 id="hello"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to only display the new element ("Hey") you would use `greetings[0]` to get the first element of the array

Comment: But what if i use the pop()array method to remove the last element in the array,And i want the element i removed to display?

Comment: `document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = greetings.pop()` because Array.pop() removes the last element in the array and returns that element.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many questions, i'm new to javascript, Since pop() returns the element it removes, How do i then display all the elements in the array after the use of the pop() array method?

Comment: do you want to display all of the array items in a single html element or give them all their own elements?

Answer (score 0):

[The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

So after running `greetings.unshift("Hey");` you end up with `greetings` being `["Hey","I","Hi","Hello"];`

Comment: Yes, Thats what i ended up with, But i want it to only display the new array added, But i don't know the array method to use.

Comment: why include it in a new array then instead of pushing it to an old array?

Comment: sorry i mean element, i want it to display the new element in the html document, But now i understand that i could just use retrieve the element from the array, Using let new = greetings[0];

Answer (score 0):

For display the Last Element you add in the array you only need this code:

```
    <h3 id="hello"></h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        ;(function(){

            //array values
            var list = ["Hi", "Hello", "Good Morning"];

            //Get the id
            const helloList = document.getElementById('hello');

            //Get the Last Value of Array
            const lastValue = list.length;

            //add a new value for the array from the last position
            //If you need change for unshift for add from the frist position
            list.push("Good Night");

            //Remove and Create a variable with the last value from array
           //If you want show the first value of array inform the key position equal 0
            var valueList = list[lastValue];

            //For select the First Position use shift()
            list.pop();

            //show the values from array
            //helloList.textContent = list.join(", ") + " and " + valueList;

            //Show the last value add in the array
            helloList.textContent = valueList;

        })()


    </script>
```